# Matlab: ratio of symbolic polynomials - extract numerator and denominator

Tags: matlab, mupad

Suppose I have a Matlab expression consisting of a ratio of polynomials of the symbolic variable 'x'. The polynomial coefficients are likewise symbolic. Is there a simple way to extract the numerator and the denominator of the expression? It is fine if the function returns either the polynomials or their coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. If you search google "MATLAB symbolic numerator denominator" the following documentation appears:
[numden](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/numden.html)

```
[N,D] = numden(A)
```

Example from MATLAB:

```
syms x y
[n,d] = numden(x/y + y/x)

n = 
x^2 + y^2

d = 
x*y
```